# Prevent closing of modal on lost focus

Tags: tailwind-ui, headless-ui

I have a modal that can submit some data to backend, and I want to prevent user from clicking out of the modal while saving is in progress.

My modal looks something like this:

```
<Transition.Root show={params.isOpen} as={Fragment}>
            <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={params.toggleBooking}>
                <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-out duration-300"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0"
                    enterTo="opacity-100"
                    leave="ease-in duration-200"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0"
                >
                    <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity"/>
                </Transition.Child>
...
```

Is there a parameter to stop the Modal from closing on clicking outside?